# Inquire or Enquire?

Tags: verbs

Could anyone explain the difference between inquire and enquire and which word to use in a specific situation. I have had a look at online dictionaries but I still don't quite get it, so could anyone give a simple explanation?

Comment: @deadly http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/enquire-or-inquire

Comment: @Kris Not sure why you posted that at me.

Comment: @Kris Your link agrees with my answer except that yours doesn't mention the spelling differences.

Comment: Please use the [site search](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquire+enquire) before asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same.

From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inquire) :

> ### inquire
>
> #### Alternative forms
>
> **[enquire](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enquire)** (chiefly British)

`enquire` is chiefly used by people from Britain while `inquire` is used by Americans.

---

As a french, I would say that `enquire` is more like `asking with care` (from [s'enquérir](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/s%27enqu%C3%A9rir) in french) and `inquire` is like `asking in order to make somebody confess` (like [inquisition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inquisition)).

The two forms came from the latin word [inquirere](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inquirere#Latin).

Comment: I like @Yohann's French approach. I'm British-born and I also like to distinguish, using "enquire" for what you and I might do, keeping "inquire" for what authority might do. Directory Enquiries, therefore, but a Public Inquiry.